# Error: Channel closed by server: 406 (PRECONDITION-FAILED) with message "PRECONDITION_FAILED

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

i was use RabbitMQ to consume data.
But, sometime in my Consumer its returning error

**Error: Channel closed by server: 406 (PRECONDITION-FAILED) with message "PRECONDITION_FAILED - delivery acknowledgement on channel 2 timed out. Timeout value used: 1800000 ms. This timeout value can be configured, see consumers doc guide to learn more"**

How can i handle that error?

Here my code

```
const services: Service[] = [
  {
    channel: "post-now",
    controller: PostNowController,
  },
  {
    channel: "post-queue",
    controller: PostQueueController,
  },
];

async function boostrap(services: Service[]) {
  try {
    const app = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(AppModule);

    amqp
      .connect(process.env.RABBITMQ_URL)
      .then((connection) => {
        services.forEach(async (service: Service) => {
          const channel = await connection.createChannel();
          const channelService = channel.assertQueue(service.channel, {
            durable: false,
          });

          if (channelService) {
            try {
              const appController = app.get(service.controller);

              channel.prefetch(30);
              channel
                .consume(
                  service.channel,
                  async (message: any) => {
                    try {
                      const data = JSON.parse(message.content.toString());
                      await appController.exec(data);

                      channel.ack(message);
                    } catch (error) {
                      channel.ack(message);
                      console.log("error consume", service.channel, error);
                    }
                  },
                  { noAck: false }
                )
                .catch((error) => {
                  logger.error(`error consume catch channel consume, ${error}`);
                });
            } catch (error) {
              logger.error(`error consume try catch, ${error}`);
            }
          }

          logger.log(`Watching channel ${service.channel} ...`);
        });
      })
      .catch((error: any) => logger.error(`error connection, ${error}`));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error boostrap, ${error}`);
  }
}

boostrap(services);
```

i was try to catch in every statement, but still not handled

I was expecting, handle that error so that the node does not restart